# error: cannot find symbol(Heroku Discord Bot)

Tags: java, heroku

I'm trying to make my Discord bot to work on Heroku but I keep getting an error. The build process works fine but the bot doesn't go online. I went to Resources --> More --> View Logs and saw an error. I understood the error as some methods not getting recognized and I removed the error one. But another one would just pop up. The code and bot works on local using IntelliJ. Anyone can help me with this please?

The error/Resource logs:

```
2021-04-18T23:58:17.202220+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   location: class Main
2021-04-18T23:58:17.226725+00:00 app[Worker.1]: src/main/java/Main.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
2021-04-18T23:58:17.226770+00:00 app[Worker.1]:         jda.setActivity(Activity.listening("!help"));
2021-04-18T23:58:17.226835+00:00 app[Worker.1]:                         ^
2021-04-18T23:58:17.226906+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   symbol:   variable Activity
2021-04-18T23:58:17.226942+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   location: class Main
2021-04-18T23:58:17.228071+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 5 errors
2021-04-18T23:58:17.230942+00:00 app[Worker.1]: error: compilation failed
2021-04-18T23:58:17.336252+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-18T23:58:17.440163+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Build/Deploy logs:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/java
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing JDK 15... done
-----> Installing Maven 3.6.2... done
-----> Executing Maven
       $ mvn -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] -------------------< org.example:CalciteDiscordBot >--------------------
       [INFO] Building CalciteDiscordBot 1.0-SNAPSHOT
       [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ CalciteDiscordBot ---
       [INFO] Deleting /tmp/build_6a1072dc/target
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ CalciteDiscordBot ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ CalciteDiscordBot ---
       [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_6a1072dc/src/main/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ CalciteDiscordBot ---
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
       [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
       [INFO] Compiling 21 source files to /tmp/build_6a1072dc/target/classes
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ CalciteDiscordBot ---
       [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_6a1072dc/src/test/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ CalciteDiscordBot ---
       [INFO] No sources to compile
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ CalciteDiscordBot ---
       [INFO] Tests are skipped.
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ CalciteDiscordBot ---
       [INFO] Building jar: /tmp/build_6a1072dc/target/CalciteDiscordBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ CalciteDiscordBot ---
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_6a1072dc/target/CalciteDiscordBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/example/CalciteDiscordBot/1.0-SNAPSHOT/CalciteDiscordBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_6a1072dc/pom.xml to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/example/CalciteDiscordBot/1.0-SNAPSHOT/CalciteDiscordBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  4.854 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-18T23:57:57Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> Worker
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 76.7M
-----> Launching...
       Released v23
       https://calcitediscordbot.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Main.java

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        JDABuilder jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("I inserted token here");
        jda.setActivity(Activity.listening("!help"));
        jda.build();

    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CalciteDiscordBot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
         
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0_246</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
         
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
         
</project>
```

Procfile:

```
Worker: java src/main/java/Main.java
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run locally with an IDE like IntelliJ, it will handle things like this to you, but you need add a plugin to create a jar with dependencies before deploying it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CalciteDiscordBot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>...</properties>
         
    <dependencies>...</dependencies>
         
    <repositories>...</repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    Main
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: After doing that and editing "<mainClass>package.MainClass</mainClass>" to "<mainClass>Main</mainClass>"(my layering: [image](https://imgur.com/a/zD2C8Pm)), Heroku still does the same thing. I tried putting it in IntelliJ but it gives me this error [image](https://imgur.com/a/CWrmHMe).

Comment: I updated my answer I miss the groupId and added some other tags, if IntelliJ still shows this kind of error for you, do a simple `mvn clean package`, IntelliJ show a lot of false positive errors to me sometimes too, don't load correctly some dependencies, etc... so I go to the manual way of doing things and works nicely.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being annoying(I never handled pom.xml without an IDE before), but it now gives me this error: [image](https://imgur.com/a/5kpTNxJ). I tried to replace the old code with the new one and Heroku gives me this error in Build Logs now: [logs](https://pastebin.com/5gvgNNq3).

Comment: relax, my bad again, I will post a full pom.xml with your file config, but IMO you need do more research on maven doc about how the pom file is structured. I presumed that you would know where put a plugin tag, anyway, now will work.

Comment: Sad news, it still doesn't work ._. I added the new pom.xml in to IntelliJ but it gives me an error(and it doesn't work on Heroku either) so I decided to add [image](https://imgur.com/a/HNXVGfd) to pom.xml. And then I ran it on Heroku, the build was successful([logs](https://pastebin.com/xZ3ZyENh)) but the bot never came online and resource logs still say errors about the same thing([Resource Logs](https://pastebin.com/dXnFMShZ)(I did reset the key btw)).

Comment: well it build, it is what the log say, but about the deploy and procfile I don't much about, but as I can remember and on this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files) you need deploy the jar build with dependencies to run properly.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, you'd have to change the pom.xml and Procfile.

Add this line to the pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>MAIN_CLASS_PATH</mainClass>
                        <name>BOT_NAME</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Add this inside of your plugins tag in your build tag. Change MAIN_CLASS_PATH to your own main class and change BOT_NAME to your project's/bot's name.

Change the Worker for the Procfile to this:

```
worker: sh target/bin/BOT_NAME
```

Same thing here ^, change BOT_NAME to your project's/bot's name.

Most credit goes to BooleanCube's Discord. And thank you @Kaneda for the help!

Comment: you could find the procfile using the link I paste on comment, don't  know why not mark my answer as accepted but it's fine, glad that worked!